# War Created by Grails ignores image files

Tags: grails, war, grails-2.0

I have grails version 2.0.4 . when i am running my application locally it runs fine .

but when i  do production deployment  in tomcat server it runs but it ignores some of files inside /image folder

and i am getting following warnings:

```
    resource.ResourceMeta While processing /css/main.css, a resource was required but not found: /images/skin/house.png
    resource.ResourceMeta While processing /css/main.css, a resource was required but not found: /images/skin/house.png
    resource.ResourceMeta While processing /css/main.css, a resource was required but not found: /images/skin/database_table.png
    resource.ResourceMeta While processing /css/main.css, a resource was required but not found: /images/skin/database_add.png
    resource.ResourceMeta While processing /css/main.css, a resource was required but not found: /images/skin/exclamation.png
    resource.ResourceMeta While processing /css/main.css, a resource was required but not found: /images/skin/exclamation.png
    resource.ResourceMeta While processing /css/main.css, a resource was required but not found: /images/skin/information.png
    resource.ResourceMeta While processing /css/main.css, a resource was required but not found: /images/skin/sorted_asc.gif
    resource.ResourceMeta While processing /css/main.css, a resource was required but not found: /images/skin/sorted_desc.gif
    resource.ResourceMeta While processing /css/main.css, a resource was required but not found: /images/skin/cancel_icon.png
    resource.ResourceMeta While processing /css/main.css, a resource was required but not found: /images/skin/cancel_icon.png
    resource.ResourceMeta While processing /css/main.css, a resource was required but not found: /images/skin/database_delete.png
    resource.ResourceMeta While processing /css/main.css, a resource was required but not found: /images/skin/database_edit.png
    resource.ResourceMeta While processing /css/main.css, a resource was required but not found: /images/skin/database_save.png
    resource.ResourceMeta While processing /css/main.css, a resource was required but not found: /images/skin/new_shadow.gif
    resource.ResourceMeta While processing /css/main.css, a resource was required but not found: /images/skin/database_table.pn
```

why its behaving so...? how to solve this problem?

Comment: ...I got the same problem. If application run from war(grails run-war), bunch of images not coming up while its fine if 'grails run-app'

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't already found an answer, this behavior seems to have come up a few times for others.  From what I've found try to following:

Least invasive - In your `` `conf/BuildConfig.groovy `` add the following:

```
compile ":webxml:1.4.1"
```

If that's a no go - put the following on your `conf/Config.groovy`

```
grails.resources.adhoc.excludes = ['**']
```

This is more invasive as it disables the Resource adhoc processing, but still leaves the plugin installed.

Last resort - remove the Resource Plugin entirely.  Comment out the line in `conf/BuildConfig.groovy`

```
//runtime ":resources:1.1.6"
```

This all comes from a thread on [Nabble](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/grails-2-0-3-2-0-4-disable-resource-plugin-for-images-td4629173.html)